# How to alpha / beta test an Android App before publishing it?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, google-play-console

I need to test my APK before publishing it to the Store.
Can I do an alpha / beta test before sending the app to production?

Answer (score 3):

You can create alpha and beta channels on your Google Play Developer console page, and then you can also gradually release your apps into production.

See official tutorials here:

[Set up alpha/beta tests](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

[Release app updates with staged rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149)

Comment: Yep, But it says: "The opt-in link only shows when an app is "Published." Apps in "Draft" or "Pending publication" won't show the opt-in link."

do I need to publish it before Alpha Beta tests?

Comment: @AlejandroJS  When you publish, it will just make the beta version available to whomever you choose, or if it's a public beta, to a small portion of the google play user base. TL;DR Publish != Public

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You have to upload apk on alpha/beta upload.Then you can make it publish. Just create your app and on playstore in upload apk section you will find alpha and beta testing

Comment: Yeah, but the Docs say: "The opt-in link only shows when an app is "Published." Apps in "Draft" or "Pending publication" won't show the opt-in link."

can't I alpha / beta test the apk before make it public? (avaiable on the play store)

Comment: you have to publish the app.
 It will be only visible through given link